# Postgres: How to prevent anyone from updating a table?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I've been trying to stop any user from updating a table
I tried

```
REVOKE UPDATE ON TABLE NYAidCrimeMean FROM CURRENT_USER;
```

but when I try to update the  table it still goes through, any pointers?

Comment: *revoking SELECT from a user might not prevent that user from using SELECT if PUBLIC or another membership role still has SELECT rights.* https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-revoke.html

Comment: okay so I tried running REVOKE UPDATE ON TABLE NYAidCrimeMean FROM PUBLIC; before the other query, but it still lets updates through and I havent created any other users with privileges

Comment: Do not ask. Read and understand the article by provided likn completely. Then search your privileges system for access rights leak - anycase we cannot help you to search in **your** system.

Comment: I'm using DBeaver and when I checked the table's permission only postgres had UPDATE permission, so I unchecked it and saved even made a new REVOKE but it still lets updates go through

Comment: `FROM CURRENT_USER`  will only revoke for the user that is current at the time the command is run. If you are looking for it to hold for all future user interactions, it will not. My guess is you can `UPDATE` because some other `ROLE` you belong to still has `UPDATE` privileges.

Comment: I guess this happens since I'm a superuser and I cant revoke privileges from it, if I login through another use it does stop updates.

Comment: You can't really stop the superuser from doing anything. After all that's the superuser and even if you revoke a privilege the superuser can always grant himself that privilege back

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I do not particular like triggers, but they have their uses. If you cannot find all the previous grants, you can get close here with one. See [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=ea3e4fa89dee6ab51333185684fd174e).

```
create or replace function no_no_no()
  returns trigger
 language plpgsql
as $$
begin 
    raise exception 'Cannot update table %s.', tg_table_name;
    return null;
end; 
$$;

create trigger No_no_no_NYAidCrimeMeanA 
  before update on NYAidCrimeMean 
  for each statement 
  execute function no_no_no();
```

If you really want to lock it down change *before update* to *before insert or update or delete or truncate*.  

Of course a superuser can disable the trigger, then do whatever they want, but eventually get to where *you must trust someone at some point*.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is as trivial as it is obvious: don't use superusers for anything but administative tasks.